# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, salesforce

When I try to open the tab this error comes in console and the grid is also not loaded.

Below are the methods for creating hyperlinks:

```
function genUrl(cellValue, rowId, rowData){
    return ("{!LEFT($CurrentPage.URL,FIND('/',$CurrentPage.URL,9))}" +rowData.siteId);
  }
  function genUrl4(cellValue, rowId, rowData){
    return ("{!LEFT($CurrentPage.URL,FIND('/',$CurrentPage.URL,9))}" + rowData.SiteActId);
  }
  function genUrl5(cellValue, rowId, rowData){
    return ("{!LEFT($CurrentPage.URL,FIND('/',$CurrentPage.URL,9))}" + rowData.AltSiteActId);
  }
  function urlTemplate6 () {
      return ({formatter:'dynamicLink',formatoptions:{url: genUrl6, target:"_blank"},
                        sorttype:"link", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew','en']}});
  }
  function genUrl6(cellValue, rowId, rowData){
    return ("{!LEFT($CurrentPage.URL,FIND('/',$CurrentPage.URL,9))}" + "apex/CountryDetail?name="+rowData.AltSiteCountry);
  }
```

definition of what data format is in each column

```
cfg.colModel = [
      {name:'siteName',index:'siteName', template:urlTemplate()},
      {name:'SiteActName',index:'SiteActName',template:urlTemplate4()},
      {name:'FullrecTime',index:'FullrecTime',template:numberTemplate()},
      {name:'AltsiteName',index:'AltsiteName',template:urlTemplate5()},
          {name:'AltSiteBringUptime',index:'AltSiteBringUptime',template:integerTemplate()},
      {name:'AltSiteCountry',index:'AltSiteCountry',template:urlTemplate6()},
```

the method where the error shows

```
              // Common formatting options
              $.jgrid.formatter.integer.thousandsSeparator = ',';
              $.jgrid.formatter.number.thousandsSeparator = ',';
              $.jgrid.formatter.number.decimalSeparator = '.';
              $.jgrid.formatter.number.decimalPlaces = 0;
              $.jgrid.formatter.currency.thousandsSeparator = ',';
              $.jgrid.formatter.currency.decimalPlaces = 0;

              // set up some global variables for use across callbacks
              window.firstLoad = true;
              // The following two to be set when we start restoring saved column state
              window.myColumnsState;
              window.isColState = false;

              window.myDefaultSearch = 'cn';

              UserTableSettings.getTableCfg(cfg.storageItemName, function(result,event){
                if (event.status){
                  if (result != null) {
                    var savedColState = JSON.parse(result.tableCfg);
                    myColumnsState = restoreColumnState (cfg.colModel, savedColState);
                  } else {
                    myColumnsState = null;
                  }
                  isColState = typeof (myColumnsState) !== 'undefined' && myColumnsState !== null;
                  $(cfg.tableName).jqGrid({
                    datatype: "local",
                    sortable: true,
                    //index: cfg.index,
                    autowidth: true,
                    shrinkToFit: true,
                    ignoreCase: true,
                    pager:cfg.pager,
                    rownumbers: true,
                    viewrecords: true,
                    viewsortcols:[true,'horizontal',true],
                    gridview: true,
                    autoencode: true,
                    height:cfg.height,
                    caption: cfg.caption,
                    rowNum:cfg.initialRows,
                    rowList:[10,20,50,100,100000000],
                    page: isColState ? myColumnsState.page : 1,
                    search: isColState ? myColumnsState.search : false,
                    postData: isColState ? { filters: myColumnsState.filters } : {},
                    sortname: isColState ? myColumnsState.sortname : cfg.initialSort,
                    sortorder: isColState ? myColumnsState.sortorder : 'desc',
                    colNames: cfg.colNames,
                    colModel: cfg.colModel,
                    storageItemName: cfg.storageItemName, // Resilinc addition
                    loadComplete: function() {
                      $("option[value=100000000]").text('All');
                      if (firstLoad) {
                        firstLoad = false;
                        if (isColState) {
                          $(this).jqGrid("remapColumns", myColumnsState.permutation, true);
                        }
                      }
                      //saveColumnState.call($(this), $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'storageItemName'), this.p.remapColumns);
                    },
                    resizeStop: function () {
                      saveColumnState.call($(this), $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'storageItemName'), $(this)[0].p.remapColumns);
                    }
                  });

                  $(cfg.tableName).navGrid(cfg.pager,{edit:false,add:false,del:false,refresh:false},{},{},{},{multipleSearch:true,multipleGroup:true, showQuery: true});
                  $(cfg.tableName).filterToolbar({searchOperators : true});
                  $.extend(true, $.ui.multiselect, {
                    locale: {
                      addAll: 'Make all visible',
                      removeAll: 'Hide All',
                      itemsCount: 'Available Columns'
                    }
                  });
                  $(cfg.tableName).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', cfg.pager, {
                      caption: "Columns",
                      buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator",
                      title: "Choose columns",
                      onClickButton: function () {
                          $(this).jqGrid('columnChooser',
                            {width: 550,
                             msel_opts: {dividerLocation: 0.5},
                             done: function (perm) {
                              if (perm) {
                                this.jqGrid("remapColumns", perm, true);
                                saveColumnState.call(this, this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'storageItemName'), perm);
                              }
                             }
                            }
                          );
                          $("#colchooser_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id) + ' div.available>div.actions')
                              .prepend('<label style="float:left;position:relative;margin-left:0.6em;top:0.6em">Search:</label>');
                      }
                  });
                  $(cfg.tableName).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', cfg.pager, {
                          caption: "",
                          buttonicon: "ui-icon-closethick",
                          title: "Clear saved table settings",
                          onClickButton: function () {
                              removeObjectFromServerStorage(cfg.storageItemName);
                          }
                      });
                    if(typeof cfg.loadData !== 'undefined')
                     cfg.loadData();
                } else {
                  // add some code here to handle a failed JS Remoting call
                }
              }, {escape:false});

function integerTemplate () {
    return ({formatter: 'integer', align: 'right', sorttype: 'integer',
        searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge'] }});
```

Answer (score 0):

This in general means that a value is defined for the variable `formatter`. However, your code contains several places where this is used so we can't be sure about the exact problem.

Take a look at the line the debugger gives you and go from there.

Did you for example attach the right javascript files? Did you forget to set a value to the variable you try to use? Keep asking yourself this kind of questions when you come across this kind of problems.

Comment: Did you include the JavaScript file in this reference? http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6

Comment: Any luck so far in solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.jgrid.formatter.integer.thousandsSeparator
```

When this line runs you get `Cannot read property 'formatter' of undefined`. Which means the expression that comes before `.formatter` is `undefined`. That expression is `$.jgrid`.

So whatever is supposed to put things at `$.jgrid` isn't working. Is this a library you are using? Is that library included on the page and loading properly? If you can get that library to load, this will likely begin to work.

Comment: Thanks Alex, but I have included the script where this function 'qGridDraw(cfg)' is defined. This works fine for other pages except for one.

Comment: Type `$.jgrid` into your javascript console on this page. What is your return value?

Comment: Exactly. So whatever you expect to be there isn't there. And you've showed no code that you think assigns a value to `$.jgrid`. Therefore the problem is not in the code you've posted. My best guess is that your library isn't loading for some reason. But if you post what the library is and how you are including it, perhaps we can help more.

Comment: The js is 
// Various templates for formatting and searching columns
    function urlTemplate () {
      return ({formatter:'dynamicLink',formatoptions:{url: genUrl, target:"_blank"},
                    sorttype:"link", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew','en']}});
}
//for every Hyperlink we need to one such function
    function urlTemplate2 () {
  return ({formatter:'dynamicLink',formatoptions:{url: genUrl2, target:"_blank"},
                    sorttype:"link", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew','en']}});
}

Comment: <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.*****, 'js/******JqGrid.js')}"/>
This way I include the js in my page

Comment: function urlTemplate3 () {
  return ({formatter:'dynamicLink',formatoptions:{url: genUrl3, target:"_blank"},
                    sorttype:"link", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew','en']}});
}
function urlTemplate4 () {
  return ({formatter:'dynamicLink',formatoptions:{url: genUrl4, target:"_blank"},
                sorttype:"link", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew','en']}});
}function urlTemplate5 () {
  return ({formatter:'dynamicLink',formatoptions:{url: genUrl5, target:"_blank"},sorttype:"link", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew','en']}});
}

Comment: What language is `<apex:includeScript>`? What script tag does that generate? Does it look right? Look at the network tab in the Chrome dev tools, and see if the request for the javascript is returning the code you expect.

Comment: This is Apex language for salesforce